# Java XML DOM with lots of data, how can I buffer it?

Tags: java

I have a Java program that is generating XML data which happens to be very large. I am using the typical parsers in javax.xml and the org.w3c.dom objects. The DOM in memory is becoming so large that it occasionally runs out of memory. Now, the reason it reaches the memory limit is because the program is generating all of the data at once and then transforming it to a String and then to a file. There are hundreds of elements being generated at once that could be made one at a time and buffered to a file rather than slowly filling the RAM. I've been looking into libraries out there but I'm a bit confused on what is good. What method should I be using to buffer this DOM document to a file rather than generating all at once?

Comment: I'd suggest you use a parser like SAX instead of DOM, as it won't load the whole document in memory. You have a good example of how to use it [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152). As SAX don't allow you to write in documents, if you need that feature you could use StAX too. It's event-based, pull-type and offers you a lot of methods to treat your document. Here's a good [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html) to start.

Comment: Yes I was looking into this. Does it work similarly to typical DOM methods?

Comment: Look at the link I gave you, it's not really hard, and really better in performance for big documents. It works perfectly.

Comment: Use StAX (Streaming API for XML).

Comment: Wait, I'm somewhat confused. I'm not trying to parse data, I'm generating data as in creating elements and appending them to a DOM. SAX will help with parsing large amounts of data but not with buffering an output of a large amount of data which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: As I said if you need to create elements, you can use StAX (well you kinda have to in that case)

Comment: Another idea would be to use [StaxMate](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/StaxMateTutorial) for handling content -- it is based on Stax API (so uses very little memory), but is bit more convenient to use; and specifically much easier than SAX. Also: even if you are just using DOM, do NOT create a String out of it: this will use even more memory and take time without any benefits. Instead you should just write the document to File straight from DOM.
There are multiple ways to do that, for example: * [Write DOM to a File using StaxMate](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/StaxMateHowToDOM) * [Write DOM to a File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Marty, I also suggest you to use the SAX. [It consumes less memory](http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/2007-08-29/).
Here's a simple sample code for SAX implementation.

```
public class SaxReader{
    public void readXML() throws Exception{
        ResultHandler oHandler                      = new ResultHandler();
        CreateParser parser                         = new CreateParser(oHandler);    
        String responseXML = "Place your XML as String HERE";
        InputSource input                                   = new InputSource(new StringReader(responseXml)); 
        input.setEncoding("UTF-8");     
        parser.parse(input);

    }
}


class ResultHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public void startDocument (){
        System.out.println("Start document");
    }

    public void endDocument (){
        System.out.println("End document");
    }

    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes attribs)throws SAXException {
        strValue = "";
        if(null!=qName && qName.equals("ID")){
            System.out.println("Starting element <ID> : "+strValue);
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException {
        strValue += new String(ch, start, length);
        System.out.println(">>>" + strValue);//Reading the values.
    }

    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if(null!=qName && qName.equals("ID")){
            System.out.println("Ending element </ID> : "+strValue);
        }
    }
}
```